# Cannot create an instance of OLE DB provider "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.16.0" for linked server "(null)"

Tags: sql, sql-server, excel, oledb

When trying to use openrowset with SQL I receive this error:

"Cannot create an instance of OLE DB provider "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.16.0" for linked server "(null)"."

```
...
sp_configure 'show advanced options', 1;  
RECONFIGURE;
GO 
sp_configure 'Ad Hoc Distributed Queries', 1
GO
RECONFIGURE
GO

select *
from openrowset('Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.16.0',
            'Excel 16.0;Database=‪C:\Users\Unixus\Desktop\teste.xlsx',
            'SELECT * FROM [teste$]') AS testeData

UPDATE teste
SET test_model = testeData.test_model
,test_pass = testeData.test_pass
FROM teste
JOIN OPENROWSET ('Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.16.0',
            'Excel 16.0;Database=‪C:\Users\Unixus\Desktop\teste.xlsx',
            'SELECT * FROM [teste$]') AS testeData ON teste.test_ID = teste.test_ID

GO
sp_configure 'Ad Hoc Distributed Queries', 0
RECONFIGURE
GO
sp_configure 'show advanced options', 0
RECONFIGURE
GO
```

Comment: Potentially you're looking for `Excel 16.0` (the build number) as opposed to `Excel 2209.0` (the version number). But also, is `‪C:\Users\Unixus\Desktop\teste.xlsx` on the SQL Server's file system? Does the Windows/AD account under which the SQL Server service executes have permissions to open and read that file? Have you closed all running instances of Excel that might have had that file open?

Comment: Changed to Excel 16.0 - same error. The file is on my machine, it is not on the SQL Server. The account has all perms and all instances of Excel are closed

Comment: The file has to be on the SQL Server itself. Either that, or on a Network Share that it can access.

Comment: I tried again, with the file being on the server and on a network share - same issue. But when I tried running the query on the server itself I get this : 
"Cannot initialize the data source object of OLE DB provider "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.16.0" for linked server "(null)"."

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a ***.xlsx** file Excel you can try it with ***'Excel 12.0 Xml'*** instead of *'Excel 16'* and if you use a ***.xls** file it should work with ***'Excel 8.0'***.

Maybe it is also necessary to set the following OLEDB Provider Options:

```
EXEC sp_configure 'Show Advanced Options', 1
RECONFIGURE
GO
EXEC sp_configure 'Ad Hoc Distributed Queries', 1
RECONFIGURE
GO
EXEC sp_MSSet_oledb_prop N'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.16.0', N'AllowInProcess', 1
GO
EXEC sp_MSSet_oledb_prop N'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.16.0', N'DynamicParameters', 1
GO
```

Last but not least: if the query will be executed from a non administrative user you have to give that account **read write access to the TEMP folder of the SQL-Server's service account** because every time you run an openrowset query, a connection string is temporarily stored there.